# is it possible to delete in app purchase?

Tags: iphone, itunes

is it possible to delete in app purchase while it is in rejected state?

i want to change product type:

from (i.e. consumable to non consumable)

Comment: or can i delete in app purchase once created and app is under rejected state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

ITunes connect documents state that the unique identifier for the purchase item cannot be modified after it is create and a type is set.

I use a reverse dns scheme with a trailing letter to differentiate:

> com.mycompany.myapp.item.c = consumable
>
> com.mycompany.myapp.item.n = non-consumable

Comment: can i remove in app purchase from associated app ? in order to completely remove in app purchase ?
and providing only one time charge..

no subsciption or any thing..

Comment: Not sure. Check the docs in iTunes Connect.  You may be able to disable in-app purchase via the developer portal.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible to delete an in-app purchase once created & app is in rejected state.

1 - Log in to iTunes Connect & navigate to "Manage Your Apps section"; chose your app in there.

2- Navigate to "Manage In-App Purchases"

3- Now you need to mark the approved in-app purchased to "NOT clear for sale". Click the first "Edit" button that lets you change the summary/details of the in-app purchase. A new form/page will open. Search for "Clear For Sale" option and select "No" against it. Save your change.

4- A "delete" button will now appear at the top left corner of in-app details page. Just click that button and the in-app will be deleted.